# Codeigniter: delete or change form button style

Tags: php, css, forms, codeigniter, submit

I'm using Codeigniter to build a form.

The submit button is:

```
echo form_submit('submit', 'Buy it', "id='bred'");
```

Now I'm processing the form in the same php file that it is:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


    $query = "INSERT INTO table (product, price) VALUES ('$product', '$price')";
    mysql_query($query) 
    or die(mysql_error());

//after inserting in the database I need to delete the submit button, so the form cannot be submitted twice

}
```

After inserting in the database I need to delete/change the css to opacity 0/change the css to display none the submit button, so the form cannot be submitted twice.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you processing the form in a controller?

Comment: You're querying without framework's methods but with the old mysql_* functions and not in the model, besides processing a form outside the controller. What else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making use of [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) will make this easy for you.

You will need to detect the submission of the form and then disable the submit button.

This code assumes that your form and button have the IDs 'myForm' and 'submitButton' respectively.

Javascript:

```
// Detect the submission of myForm
$('form#myForm').bind('submit', function() {

    // Disable the submit button and fade to half opacity 
    $('input#submitButton').attr("DISABLED", true).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Except that the way you do isn't save:
Due to "echo" the button you have no possibility to delete it with PHP

A (not very stylish) way would be to echo some JS code that deletes the button.

Comment: how would that be that way in JS? Been trying a lot, but nothing affects the button .. I'm going nuts